# Virtual Interfaces Unable to send packages in DD-WRT WR741 v2

Tags: wireless-router, dd-wrt, network-interface

I'm using a TP-Link WR741ND v2, with the  DD-WRT v24-sp2 (07/20/12) std.

It has been working for the last 3 monthes, perfectly ok, but suddenly the virtual interfaces stopped sending packets.

I tried the 30/30/30 reset, succes in reseting (no success in solving the problem).  I reverted back to stock, downloaded ddwrt again and installed the same firmware again, with no success.

It only happens with the virtual interfaces.

When connecting to the router with a wireless device it gives the information that the ath0.1 is recieving packages but 0 packages sent.
Tried to deactivate encryption but it did not succeed either way.  It only receives packages.

```
Received (RX) 135 OK, no error 
Transmitted (TX) 0 OK, no error
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating to the testing firmware found [here](http://www.dd-wrt.com/dd-wrtv2/down.php?path=downloads/others/eko/BrainSlayer-V24-preSP2/2012/) solved the problem